# Delphi Synapse TUDPBlockSocket RecvPacket returned 10054

Tags: delphi, udp

Please help me understand what's going on.

What could mean getting an 10054 "Connection reset by peer" error on executing RecvPacket of TUDPBlockSocket?

This happens on Server side very rarely. In the meantime, I see 10060 "Connection timed out" on the client's side.

I do not understand how this is possible at all, because udp works without connection setup. And the RecvPacket function should return an already received packet.

Server code:

```
 FServerSock := TUDPBlockSocket.Create;
 FServerSock.Bind('0.0.0.0', IntToStr(Port));

....
s := FServerSock.RecvPacket(10);
if ((FServerSock.LastError <> 0) and (FServerSock.LastError <> 10060)) then
  Begin
    Log.AddError(FServerSock.LastErrorDesc); //<--10054 found here
  end
else   
  Begin
      if (s <> '') then
        Begin
          FServerSock.SendString('ack');
          ...
        end;
  end
```

Client code:

```
  FUDP.Connect(ServerHost, IntToStr(ServerPort));
  if (FUDP.LastError = 0) then
    Begin
      FUDP.SendString(AStr);
      if (FUDP.LastError = 0) then
        Begin
          s := FUDP.RecvPacket(5000);
          if (FUDP.LastError = 0) then
            Begin
              result := (s = 'ack');
```

Comment: This code cannot raise 10054 on the server side, since there is no connection to reset. But the client is using `connect()`, which creates a 1-to-1 relationship in UDP, which affords additional error handling. But 10060 is not related to that. The server is likely just not calling `SendString()`, causing the client's `RecvPacket()` to time out.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately it happens.